# Erro ao rodar projeto em Angular

Tags: angular, npm

Instalei o angular: **npm install -g @angular/cli** e criei um projeto. Ao tentar rodar **ng serve** eu pego esse erro:

> The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a
> project definition could not be found.

Já atualizei **ng update @angular/cli @angular/core** e mesmo com o update continua a mensagem. Dei um ng v e recebi isso:

> Angular CLI: 10.0.4
>
> Node: 10.16.3
>
> OS: win32 x64
>
> Angular:
>
> ...
>
> Ivy Workspace:
>
> Package                      Version
>
> ---
>
> @angular-devkit/architect    0.1000.4
> @angular-devkit/core         10.0.4
> @angular-devkit/schematics   10.0.4
> @schematics/angular          10.0.4
> @schematics/update           0.1000.4
> rxjs                         6.5.5

Alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

**Edit1**

> {     "resource": "/c:/Projetos/NetTestes/Nettestes/angular.json",
> "owner": "*generated_diagnostic_collection_name*#1",
> "severity": 4,
> "message": "Property Nettestes is not allowed.",
> "startLineNumber":
> 6,    "startColumn": 5,   "endLineNumber": 6,     "endColumn": 16 }

Comment: Complementando apenas. No angular.json eu tenho isso: **Property Nettestes is not allowed.**

Answer (score 0):

Para executar o comando `ng serve` necessita de estar dentro do projeto Angular.

Se o projeto encontra-se na pasta `Documentos/AngularProject/` necessita de executar o comando dentro da pasta `AngularProject/`.

Se o comando `ng serve` não for reconhecido necessita de coloca-lo nas variaveis globais do sistema.

Comment: Filipe, eu estou dentro da pasta do projeto. Quanto a isso não tem problema. Acontece que qualquer projeto que eu crio, já criei 3 agora e todos quando eu executo(ng serve) me dá esse erro.

Comment: Pode colocar o erro da consola em maior detalhe?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o que eu pego na aba Problem, na aba Debug Console não vem nada

Comment: O erro está ai na propriedade  `"Property Nettestes is not allowed."`

Comment: E como resolvo isso, Filipe, sabe me dizer? Já fiz update e mesmo assim continua e isso para todo projeto que começo

Comment: Desinstalei o Angular, dei um clean cache e reinstalei e continua dando o erro